# How to fix ssh authentication error while working with Eclipse and Git

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, bitbucket-server

I am using Git, Eclipse and Bitbucket. I am able to commit and push using command line. When I try to push any file from Eclipse I will get error as:

```
ssh://<giturl>.git: No more authentication methods available
```

Although using Eclipse I am able to add and commit that file just not able to push. What could be possible reason?

Comment: Did you add your private SSH key in _Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2_? If yes, show your _Push_ configuration.

Comment: yes I added ssh to 2 places. - 1. bitbucket ->add SSH key              2.  in eclipse Window > Preferences: General > Network Connections > SSH2.  what do u mean by "show your Push configuration".. from where will I get it?

Comment: In the _Git Repositories_ view, right-click on the node _(your repository) > Remotes > origin > (second/last child)_ and choose _Configure Push_.

Comment: @howlger You're right!

Answer (score 10):

Add your git account private key to eclipse. Go to:

- Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> SSH2

  - Choose `.ssh home`
  - Choose `Private key/s`
  - `Apply` and `Close`

Retry commit